# How to merge two remote branches in Git without using push or pull?

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to merge two branches which are in my remote repo without using push or pull commands?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? I ask because it doesn't seem to achieve anything useful.

Comment: Well, an actual _merge_ takes place on GitHub, and in fact does not involve pull/push, but rather just clicking the green "merge" button.  Can you explain what you have in mind here?

Comment: I am currently doing a summer internship program and i am new to Git. My mentor has given me the above task. I tried googling it but didnt found any solution.

Comment: Did you see this? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153107/can-i-do-a-git-merge-entirely-remotely

Answer (score 0):

You could use lower-level commands instead of the high-level push/pull.

For example:

1. do [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) to download the remote state.
2. do a merge locally.
3. [git send-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-pack) instead of push.